# CSS: Show an image and a div next to each other in list item

Tags: html, css

When I set out this morning the task seemed simple: build a list of elements; each element consists of a thumbnail, a title, and a sub-title.

I'd like to have the image left aligned with the title and sub-title next to it. If you take a look at a YouTube video page: the Related Videos box has a similar layout.

UPDATE: *To be more specific: I'm trying to produce a two column layout: image on the left, text on the right. Some of the suggested solutions result in the text being wrapped around the image.*

Here the HTML structure:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="one.jpg"><div class="content">Title<br>sub-title</div></li>
  <li><img src="two.jpg"><div class="content">Another Title<br>sub-title</div></li>
</ul>
```

With no CSS, the text is displayed below the image. I tried many things, **float:left** on the image and/or the div. Nothing helped.

The closest I got was setting float:left for the **img** tag. But then the second list item was drawn halfway into the first one.

Am I taking the wrong approach? Do I need to structure the HTML differently?

Thanks!
Mark.

Comment: Depending on your doctype, make sure to use the correct form of the line-break tag - you might need to use the self-closing `<br/>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `img` inside the `div`, then you can float it. Then clear the float, e.g. by using a `br`:

```
 <li><div class="content"><img src="one.jpg">Title<br>sub-title</div><br style="clear:both"></li>
```

CSS:

```
 .content img {float:left}
```

Better yet, get rid of the div altogether (you can style the `li` directly) and use `h2` and `h3` for the headings (so as to keep the markup semantic).

Comment: Very close! The only problem I have now is that the text is wrapped around the image. I'd like to have the text next to the image. Imagine a table with two columns...

Comment: @Mark: in that case, leave the `img` outside of the `div`, float *both* the `img` and the `div`, *specify a width* for the `div`, and clear the floats using the `br`. The key here is to specify a width for the div so that the combined width of the div and the image fits into the width of the list. Otherwise, the div is floated underneath the image.

Comment: I experienced better results when the `<br style="clear:both">` is inside the `<div>` (no additional line break before next item, as the line break is at the end of the text within the `<div>`)

Answer (score 2):

you could give each `<li>` a class and apply

```
background url(image path) no-repeat;
```

then give a padding left equal to the width of the image to move text over and reveal the image

Comment: I like this method and have used it plenty

Answer (score 1):

Try `<span>` in place of `<div>`.  Span is inline and and div is boxed.  (There are other things you can do to make div inline, but I expect they would break the rest of your page.)

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube related views uses DIVs, not UL>LI combinations. Here's a scrap of their markup:

```
<div class="video-entry ">
        <a class="video-thumb-90" href="/watch?v=z-ze42I6NEo&amp;feature=related">
<img alt="Hereford Utd v Newcastle Utd 5 Feb 1972 (Hereford Utd Goals)" qlicon="z-ze42I6NEo" class="vimg90" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/z-ze42I6NEo/default.jpg" title="Hereford Utd v Newcastle Utd 5 Feb 1972 (Hereford Utd Goals)"><button onmousedown="yt.analytics.urchinTracker('/Events/VideoWatch/QuickList+AddTo')" onmouseout="yt.www.watch.quicklist.mouseOutQuickAdd(this)" onmouseover="yt.www.watch.quicklist.mouseOverQuickAdd(this)" onclick="return yt.www.watch.quicklist.onQuickAddClick(this, this.getAttribute('ql'), 'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/z-ze42I6NEo/default.jpg', 'Hereford Utd v Newcastle Utd 5 Feb 1972 (Hereford Utd Goals)')" class="master-sprite QLIconImg addtoQL90" title="Add Video to QuickList" ql="z-ze42I6NEo"></button><span style="display: none;" class="quicklist-inlist">Added to <br> Quicklist</span><span class="video-time"><span>0:45</span></span></a>
        <div class="video-main-content">
            <div class="video-mini-title"><a rel="nofollow" title="Hereford Utd v Newcastle Utd 5 Feb 1972 (Hereford Utd Goals)" href="/watch?v=z-ze42I6NEo&amp;feature=related">Hereford Utd v Newcastle Utd 5 Feb 1972 (Herefo...</a></div>
            <div class="video-view-count">73,309 views</div>
            <div class="video-username"><a href="/user/Boney1960">Boney1960</a></div>

        </div>
        <div class="video-clear-list-left"></div>
    </div>
```

If you want to copy an effect you see, just examine the document's HTML. It's pretty simple to do.

Comment: I did that. Firebug rules! I could reproduce the layout, but ran into another problem: the entries would always consume the complete width of the page (unless set to a specific value). I'd like the largest entry to determine the width of the whole list so that I can center the list eventually.