# How to make an image and a div start from the same horizontal line in an ordered list CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a responsive chat application and now I want to design how the messages appear on the screen.By displaying the message, I must display the image of the user at the left and next to it a `div` containing the details of the message: the name of the user who wrote it and the time next to it, and in the same `div` but bellow username and time display the content of the message.

Also , the `div` that contains the message details is separated from the user image and has his own style.

I set the image next to the message `div` in the same line but they don't start from the same horizontal line no matter what is the size of the `div`,and then ,the message grows from the top to the bottom.

The chat board must be an ordered list `<ol>`,so here is my code for two list items(two messages): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLbghtv8/1/)

and here's an illustration of what I want:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtjE.jpg)

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380417/css-show-an-image-and-a-div-next-to-each-other-in-list-item) because the answer suggested is suggesting putting the image inside the div of the message's details,and that is not what I want.

How can achieve that?

Any help is apprecieted. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hello , please explain why the question got minus? so I can do better next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i've done:

- I removed the inline css as it's not a best practice to use it for this type of things
- I wrapped the chat into a common container
- I created a conditional class called .right if you need to add a message aligned on the right hand side

The code i've used is faking the use of tables.

basically, i set the common container to be `display:table` and then the icon is a table cell and the message is another table cell.

You can then use `vertical-align: top` to align them at the top line, or other options to move the to the middle or bottom of the container div.

Here's the full code with two messages as an example (left and right):
https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/EvZKQv?editors=1100

**html**

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <div class="message-container">
   <div class="user-icon">
    <img src="https://i.fantasyfootball.telegraph.co.uk/football/premierleague/images/elements/stat_1516.png?ver=350" />
   </div>
   <div class="message">
    <span class=username> username</span>
    <span class="time"> 16:00</span>
    <span class="user-message">message content here message content here message content here</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>

 <li class="right">
  <div class="message-container">
   <div class="message">
    <span class=username> username</span>
    <span class="time"> 16:00</span>
    <span class="user-message">message content here message content here message content here</span>
   </div>
   <div class="user-icon">
    <img src="https://i.fantasyfootball.telegraph.co.uk/football/premierleague/images/elements/stat_1516.png?ver=350" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>

</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
ol li {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ol li.right {
  text-align: right;
}
ol li .message-container {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
ol li .message-container .user-icon {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ol li .message-container .user-icon img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
ol li .message-container .message {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  border-radius: 0.5625rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.03125rem;
  border-color: #f4f4f4;
  background: #859756;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
ol li .message-container .message span.username {
  font-family: Nunito;
  color: #450026;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
ol li .message-container .message span.user-message {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

(in the codepen example, i'm using less css to create the css file, so that's why it looks a bit different)

I hope this helps in any way.